# Sign PGP key with another key in PHP

Tags: php, gnupg, pgp

Actually exactly what is written in the title.

I couldn't really figure out how to do this or if this is even possible and it also seems like there is no info about this online.

To be honest I tried nothing as I really don't know where to start and I'm still learning PHP & Co.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating the problem. To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and its linked resources.
  Here are two articles to get you started: [GPG to Sign Messages](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-gpg-to-encrypt-and-sign-messages)
[PHP Docs on GPG](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gnupg-encrypt.php)

Comment: @James thanks for your help but I know how to generate a key pair and how to encrypt and sign files or text but I want to be able to sign another public key with PHP before or after importing it.

Comment: It sounds like you need to research "multiparty encryption"